# Path recursively

Tags: windows, path

I tried searching this on Google and didn't really learn anything as the search results usually pertain to other recursive subjects. What I would like to know is if a folder is in Path is it defined recursively (on Windows)?

I want to create a `C:\StandalonePrograms` and add that to path. It will contain a bunch of programming languages and other programs that usually come from zip files. I want to know that if by adding the program directory to it I can call all of the programs.

For example if I have `C:\StandalonePrograms\SomeProgram` can I open up a command prompt type `someCommand` and expect it to run from the `C:\StandalonePrograms\SomeProgram\bin` folder?

Or do I need to explicitly define `C:\StandalonePrograms\SomeProgram\bin` in my Path?

If I can't are there any workarounds to achieve the situation I want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify each directory individually, the PATH mechanism doesn't walk through subdirectories.

A workaround could be a directory full of batch files (of some sort) that start the real tools with full path

Comment: Instead of creating batch files, just add `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` to `%PATH%` and make sure every program has a shortcut there. Then add `.LNK` to `%PATHEXT%` so that you can type `<program_name>` instead of `<program_name>.lnk`.

Comment: Note that the program will, by default, start in some folder inside `Program Files`, meaning `<program_name> arg.txt` will use a file called `arg.txt` inside `Program Files`, rather than the working directory. To fix that, right-click the shortcut, select `Properties` and fill in an empty string `""` for the `Start in` field. Alternatively, follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163798/2153942 .

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround. Save this as "SetMyPath.bat" (or with another name):

```
@echo off
set dir=%*
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /ad /o:d /b "%dir:"=%"') do set path=%%i;!path!
cmd
```

(Here, `"%dir:"=%"` is only needed to permit you to omit quotation marks around the directories with space in the names when calling this file. If you don't need this, then `%1` would do instead.)

This file takes one command-line argument: the directory. It will launch a new copy of `cmd.exe`, where files under the given directory will be available:

```
C:\> mysqldump.exe
File not found.
C:\> SetMyPath.bat C:\Program Files\MySQL
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\> mysqldump.exe
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
C:\> exit
```

In this example, the first command shows that `mysqldump.exe` is not on the path. After you execute the batch file, a new `cmd.exe` is launched, where `mysqldump.exe` is available. When you finish working with it, `exit` returns you to the original copy of `cmd.exe`.

If there are two copies of the `.exe` file under different subdirectories, the copy in the most recently updated directory will be launched (because of `/o:d`). In this example, assuming that the directory of the most recent version of MySQL was updated last, the most recent version of `mysqldump.exe` will be launched.

The batch file can be modified to guarantee that the most recent copy of the `.exe` be launched (ask me in a comment if you need it).