# How to start phoenix application without showing terminal in Windows 11

Tags: windows, elixir, phoenix-framework, release

### Background

I am creating a simple Phoenix umbrella application  to run on a client's Windows 11 machine and my objective is to have something like an `.exe` file for running said application.

### Code

I am creating the application and releasing it using Elixir's normal release procedure, using the commands:

```
mix phx.new demo --umbrella --no-ecto --no-dashboard --no-gettext --no-mailer
cd demo_umbrella
mix deps.get

# set MIX_ENV=prod before doing this last step!
mix release demo
```

For those of you curious, this is the `releases` function I am using inside my `mix.exs`:

```
  defp releases,
    do: [
      demo: [
        applications: [
          demo_web: :permanent,
          runtime_tools: :permanent
        ],
        include_executables_for: [:windows]
      ]
    ]
```

Now, this basic setup will create a `.bat` file:  `_build\prod\rel\demo\bin\demo.bat` that I can start and stop via the following commands:  `_build\prod\rel\demo\bin\demo {start | stop}`.

### Problems & Research

Users that know programming can simply open a terminal in Windows, type  `_build\prod\rel\demo\bin\demo start` and the application will launch (accessible via localhost:4000).

But users normally don't have such knowledge. So I want something as close to an `.exe` file as possible.

I have tried using Bakeware:

- https://github.com/bake-bake-bake/bakeware/issues/136

And its spiritual successor, Burrito:

- https://github.com/burrito-elixir/burrito/issues/111

Unfortunately, both fail to work for Windows 11. This leads me to try the shortcut approach.
Here I create Windows shortcut to `demo.bat` and I specify in the target path the commands:

- [Making a Windows shortcut start relative to where the folder is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169556/making-a-windows-shortcut-start-relative-to-where-the-folder-is)

Which in this case will be `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start "" "%CD%\demo.bat" start`

Now, all is fine and dandy, but there is a problem:

1. the console always appears.

### Questions

So this leaves me to the following questions:

1. How do I prevent the console from showing?
2. Does `demo.bat` include the erlang VM and the elixir version needed to run the application? Or do I need to have those installed in the client's machine ?
3. I am under the impression that Elixir releases are supposed to include everything needed (https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/config-and-releases.html):

> A release is a self-contained directory that consists of your application code, all of its dependencies, plus the whole Erlang Virtual Machine (VM) and runtime. Once a release is assembled, it can be packaged and deployed to a target as long as the target runs on the same operating system (OS) distribution and version as the machine that assembled the release.

, but in case this bat file does not include everything, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Prevent the console from showing: https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window

and this:

https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way

2.) No I don't think it will.  I think you will need to install the Erlang VM on the target machine. I'm speaking from a bit of experience here (although it's been literally years since I tried to deploy an Elixir app on someone else's Windows box).

3.) Bear in mind that most advice about deploying Elixir apps simply doesn't hold with Elixir on Windows.  I used to try to help @bitwalker to get releases going on Windows and between the two of us we never could get a satisfactory approach.

If there's some way you could run your app under WSL that'd probably remove some of the difficulties.

4.) I know you didn't ask but having the Phoenix server start on a Windows 11 box on bootup will likely require you to monkey with Windows Services.  This is also not a trivial thing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @OnorioCatenacci (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77283988/1337392) was essential and pointed me in the right direction. However for the sake of completeness, I will still detail exactly what I did:

1. Follow instructions to create the project from the question above. (you may need to enable server options in `config/prod.exs`)
2. Go to `demo_umbrella\_build\prod\rel\demo\bin` where the newly created `demo.bat` file is
3. Create a file called `invisible.vbs` and add in the following content:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "", 0, False
```

4. Create a Windows shortcut, that looks like this:

[image]

The value on the target field is:

`%windir%\system32\wscript.exe invisible.vbs "demo.bat start"`

5. Upon clicking the shortcut, the application will be launched behind the scenes and you will be able to check it under `localhost:4000`.

This shortcut will run the files from the folder it is in, so you can safely move things around provided you always keep it in the same folder the rest of the files are.

Being a shortcut, it also means you can change the icon to anything you want.

---

Regarding his answer:

2. This is also somewhat similar to my experience. Thanks for confirming.
3. If I were to do that, my customers would have to enable WSL features on windows. Most of them would have a heart attack at the mere prospect of doing so =(
4. Thankfully, this is not an elephant I plan on eating :D