# change path of mini buffer after launching emacs

Tags: emacs

When I try to use a command such as M-x pdb, it will try to load files from the current path. How do I change the load path of the the mini-buffer on the fly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464/changing-the-default-folder-in-emacs

Comment: @huitseeker: that seems to be about windows and it doesn't say how to change the path on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> `cd` <kbd>Enter</kbd> (then enter your target working directory)