# Change default save folder in LispBox

Tags: emacs, lisp-in-a-box

So I've finally decided to learn Lisp.  I'm reading [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) and I'm using [Lispbox](http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/) (not the one the book recommends - it's no longer available, but it seems this is suitable nonetheless).

So far in my career I have managed to avoid wresting with emacs, but I guess that part of my life is over :-)  Actually, I'm kind of excited - this is a brand new world.

When saving .lisp files, the out-of-the-box setup dumps these files into the `lispbox-0.7` folder (which is also the LISPBOX_HOME env.var).  My math teacher taught me, "If you don't know what you're doing, at least do it neatly."  So I want to at least keep my work in a nice tidy folder.  I can specify the full path on saving/loading.  But can I tell (lispbox|emacs|whatever) to use a different folder by default?

If it matters: I will likely use the Windows version more often, but I also have a setup on Ubuntu.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464/changing-the-default-folder-in-emacs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263758/how-to-change-emacs-config-in-lisp-in-a-box?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059833/how-to-set-default-working-directory-in-emacs-troubleshooting?lq=1).  I tried adding these to the `.emacs` file (one at a time):

```
(setq default-directory "C:/Work/lisp/")    
(cd "C:/Work/lisp/")
```

To open the `.emacs` file I used <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>`~/.emacs`

If I try changing the LispBox shortcut's "Start in" property, it fails to load at all.

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`cd c:/work/lisp` does work, but I have to do it every time I launch LispBox

What I'm doing in the meantime:  I've created a separate `lisp` folder beside the `lispbox-0.7` folder.  That way I can prepend `../lisp/` before any filename.  This isn't so bad, especially with the tab auto-complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

The reason modifying `.emacs` wasn't working is because of the `lispbox.bat` file.  It has this line:

```
%EMACS% --no-init-file --no-site-file --eval=%TO_EVAL%
```

So took out the two "no" parameters, leaving this...

```
%EMACS% --eval=%TO_EVAL%
```

...and it worked.

This worried me, though.  Why would the default not want to load the `.emacs` file?  I guess once I understand all of this better I'll have an answer.  Until then, I restored the above, the changed this line...

```
set TO_EVAL="(progn (load \"lispbox\") (slime))"
```

...to this...

```
set TO_EVAL="(progn (load \"lispbox\") (slime) (cd \"C:/work/lisp/\"))"
```

Now I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Lisp Box, and not all of what you describe is clear to me. But here goes.

It sounds like you are looking for a way to make `c:/work/lisp` the default directory when you start Emacs. For that, using an MS Windows shortcut, putting that folder in the `Start in` field does indeed accomplish that.  But you speak of a `LispBox` shortcut's `Start in`.  If by that you just mean an Emacs shortcut, then it should work.

But of course you need to *use Windows syntax* for the folder - not `c:/work/lisp`, but `c:\work\lisp`.

Is that what the problem was?

The Windows shortcut is a Windows thing. Emacs is different: it accepts `/` as a folder separator.

---

*Tip:* If that solves your problem, you might also want to start Emacs in Dired mode on that same folder, that is, if that folder is the one you will use a lot.  To do that, add that folder at the end of the command line - again, using Windows syntax, but between double-quotes:

```
c:\your\path\to\runemacs.exe "c:\work\lisp"
```

Comment: Good advice, but that wasn't it.  The shortcut launches the `lispbox.bat` file, which in turn launches `runemacs.exe`  I'm pretty sure I flipped / to \ but I may not have.  Doesn't work even when correct, i.e. `C:\Work\lisp`.

Comment: In that case, if an explicit `(setq default-directory "c:/work/lisp")` in your init file does not work then look for a hook or user option (customization variable) in the Lispbox Emacs code. You need to somehow evaluate such a sexp after the Lispbox application has started Emacs.

Comment: There is also apparently a [mailing list for Lispbox development](http://common-lisp.net/mailman/listinfo/lispbox-devel).  Try asking there. I'm sure this is a common need. There might even be a FAQ for it (or perhaps there should be).

Comment: the link to the mailing list is broken (not your fault - it's broken on the Lispbox home page).  Now that I have my answer, maybe I'll see what's on their github and add my findings if they're not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting lispbox.bat from the directory you want to save files to.  For example, from the OS command prompt:

```
cd c:\work\lisp
path-to-bat-file\lispbox.bat
```

You can also cd to c:\work\lisp in listbox.bat before it executes Emacs. For Linux it looks like this in lispbox.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${0:0:2}" = "./" ]; then
    export LISPBOX_HOME=`pwd`/../../..
else
    export LISPBOX_HOME=`dirname $0`/../../..
fi
cd ~/work/lisp
export SBCL_HOME=${LISPBOX_HOME}/sbcl-1.0.42/lib/sbcl
exec ${LISPBOX_HOME}/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --no-init-file --no-site-file --eval='(progn (load "lispbox") (slime))'
```