# emacs windows find file slash backslash both in the path

Tags: windows, emacs, path

When I use **c-x c-f** to find a file in emacs windows, the mini-buffer shows:

```
Find file: D\Workspace\emacs/
```

I have set the *start in* directory to "D\Workspace\emacs" for windows emacs app *exe shortcut*.
Though this does not affect my work. But both **slash** and **backslash** in the path looks ugly.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464/changing-the-default-folder-in-emacs help?

Comment: You could always try `ido-mode`. It converts everything to forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

The following code in your configuration should help:

```
(dolist (b (buffer-list))
  (with-current-buffer b
    (when default-directory
      (subst-char-in-string ?\\ ?/ default-directory 'inplace))))
(when (default-value 'default-directory)
  (subst-char-in-string ?\\ ?/ (default-value 'default-directory) 'inplace))
```